# Testing Middleware and get TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm doing tests for middleware function and get an error:

TypeError: *** is not a function

My test.js

```
describe('Login', () => {
    it('it must check that function create the token', () => {
      const req = {
        body: { email: 'user@mail.com', password: '12345' }
      }
      const res = { locals: sinon.spy() }
      return authMiddleware.login(req, res)  // authMiddleware.test.js:41
        .then(res => {
          expect(res.locals.token).to.not.be.undefined;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
  });
```

and middleware.js

```
module.exports = User => ({

  login(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) return res.sendStatus(401);
    return User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
      .then(user => {
        if (!user) return res.sendStatus(401);
        if (!user.isValidPassword(req.body.password)) return 
res.sendStatus(401);
        let payload = { id: user.id };
        let token = jwt.encode(payload, config.auth.jwtSecret);
        res.locals.token = token;
        next();
      })
      .catch(next);
  },
 });
```

Error:

```
TypeError: authMiddleware.login is not a function
at Context.it (test/api/middleware/authMiddleware.test.js:41:35)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is authMiddleware? Is it pointing correctly to the User module?

Comment: This module authorize user and transfers to controller the token. The controller send token for client.

Comment: how do you require(authMiddleware) in the test? shouldn't it be authMiddleware(user).login(...) ?

Comment: @SergeiR you don't understand, just post your complete code. Obviously, it looks like you are not exporting / exposing the module or requiring it correctly that is why the type error

Comment: Yes error was because I don't send User =>  const authMiddleware = require('..../authMiddleware')(User);

Answer (score 0):

Your `middleware.js` file exports an arrow function that accepts the `User` parameter. The return value of this function is an object which has a `login` method with an express middleware signature.

You should invoke `login` middleware like this:

```js
const { login: loginMiddleware } = require('./middleware')(req.body);
loginMiddleware(req, res, next);
```